# What is needed in order to run the JTestR samples? (or using JTestR at all)

Tags: java, testing, jruby

I've spent some time trying to use JTestR. I haven't succeeded in any way :\

Take this sample for instance:
https://github.com/olabini/jtestr/tree/master/examples/simple_maven_project

Running 'mvn test' here gives me:

> [ERROR] Plugin
>   org.jtestr:jtestr:0.7-SNAPSHOT or one
>   of its dependencies could not be
>   resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.jtestr:jtestr:jar:0.7-SNAPSHOT:
>   Could not find artifact
>   org.jtestr:jtestr:pom:0.7-SNAPSHOT

I'm also unable to build the current master branch from the github repository.

I then tried downloading the v0.6 dist and following the [Getting Started](http://jtestr.codehaus.org/Getting+Started) section, but with errors:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.jtestr:jtestr:0.6:test (default)
>   on project jtestr: Execution default
>   of goal org.jtestr:jtestr:0.6:test
>   failed: Plugin org.jtestr:jtestr:0.6
>   or one of its dependencies could not
>   be resolved: Could not find artifact
>   org.jtestr:jruby-complete:jar:r1c672b495cfd204421f4a7aed17f6135e730a3b2

I suspect that this is because I've put my jtestr jar file in the wrong place. Where should it be?

Answer (score 1):

now this is because for some reason maven could not resolve one of JTestR's dependency - a custom packaged complete jruby jar - there's a simple solution although :

1. download the jar from http://dist.codehaus.org/jtestr/
   http://dist.codehaus.org/jtestr/jruby-complete-r1c672b495cfd204421f4a7aed17f6135e730a3b2.jar
2. then hand install it to Your local maven repository :
   `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.jtestr -DartifactId=jruby-complete -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=r1c672b495cfd204421f4a7aed17f6135e730a3b2 -Dfile=[PATH_TO_DOWNLOADED.jar]`